# ListItemTemplate stopped working after latest SAPUI5 update 1.56.5

Tags: combobox, sapui5

I upgraded to the latest version of `SAPUI5 - 1.56.5` and the `ListItemTemplate` inside Combobox stopped working. Although the dropdown length is equal to the number of items supposed to be displayed, there is no text displayed in the dropdown.

```
   var formatterItemTemplate = function (myText) {
       return myText.toUpperCase());
   };

   var oItemTemplate = new ListItem({
     key: "{CityId}",
     text: {
       path: 'Address/CityName',
       formatter: formatterItemTemplate
     }
   });

   var oComboBox = oCore.byId('MyComboBox');
   oComboBox.bindItems({
      path: "/Companies/FetchCompanyBasedonCity" + "(CompanyCode='" +oModelData.CompanyCode + "',CityId=" +oModelData.CityId+ ")",",
      template: oItemTemplate,
      templateShareable: true,
      parameters: {
          $expand: 'Address'
      },
   });
```

Please note that `FetchCompanyBasedonCity` in the path attribute is a custom function implemented in .NET which returns a list of companies based on the parameters.

Even If I remove the formatter and simply assign text as below, the text inside dropdown in not populated.

```
  var oItemTemplate = new ListItem({
      key: "{CityId}",
      text: "{Address/CityName}"
  });
```

If I revert to my previously used version `1.54.3`, everything works fine. Any ideas why the same code doesn't work with new SAPUI5 version 1.56.5

Comment: You can file an issue here if it's an obvious bug: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: Thanks Marc, I have reported the issue at Github.

Comment: Kindly share the screenshot of ERROR..

Comment: Hi Inizio, there is no error, just the combobox is empty

Comment: Issue reported in GitHub : https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2189

Comment: Please share the error from console in chrome or any browser you testing on.